# Копирование унаследованной части в перегрузке оператора присваивания потомка

Tags: c++, наследование, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор-копирования

Есть базовый абстрактный класс

```
class entity {
protected:
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;

    entity(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);

...
}
```

А также его конкретный потомок, с перегрузкой конструктора копирования, оператора присваивания и деструктора.

```
class item : public entity {
    char* name;
public:
    item(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, const char* name);
    item(const item& anotherItem);
    item& operator=(const item& anotherItem);
    ~item;
...
}
```

Реализация перегрузки оператора присваивания

```
item& operator=(const item& anotherItem) {
    x1 = anotherItem.x1;
    x2 = anotherItem.x1;
    x3 = anotherItem.x1;
    x4 = anotherItem.x1;

    //Далее глубокое копирование char*
}
```

Итак. Очевидно, что при реализации конструктора копирования будет `: entity(x1, x2, y1, y2) {...}`, что заметно сократит код. В перегрузке же оператора присваивания так сделать нельзя и приходится руками копировать все координаты. Как можно этого избежать и сразу скопировать родительскую часть потомка?

Comment: Кстати, там, где у вас "Далее глубокое копирование char*", надеюсь, не забыто сначала его удалить? А с присвоением - если есть реализация `swap` - обмена двух "внутренностей", и копирующий конструктор - то можно воспользоваться идиомой `T& operator=(T x){ swap(x); return *this; }`

Comment: Что это:  object(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Разве после присвоения оператором по умолчанию, поле`name` этих объектов не будет одна и та же область в памяти?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Прошу прощения, опечатка. Там entity().

Comment: @Александр нет, он будет точно копировать данные объекта класса, а то, о чём вы говорите - копирования адреса указателя, что действительно может привести к беде, а так как у вас только целочисленные значения, то создавать конструктор копий или перегруженный оператор присвоения не требуется

Comment: @AyratArifullin я думал речь идет о целесообразности перегрузки конструктора копирования класса item. В entity я же ничего не перегружал.

Comment: @Александр это имело бы смысл, если бы вы использовали указатели в качестве полей своей класса

Comment: @Александр Пардон, не посмотрел. Тогда лучше вместо указателя взять `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно вызвать оператор присваивания предка `entity::operator =(anotherItem);`